# Assembly name from MSBUILD

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup

I am developing an app that reads a MSBUILD file ( *.csproj ) to pull out various bits of information. A previous question on here revealed that I can get the resource files being used in the following manner

```
        Project project = new Project();
        project.Load(fullPathName);

        var embeddedResources =
            from grp in project.ItemGroups.Cast<BuildItemGroup>()
            from item in grp.Cast<BuildItem>()
            where item.Name == "EmbeddedResource"
            select item;
```

Now I want to get the assembly name for the project. My initial to look in the "BuildProperyGroup" for a "BuildProperty" with "Name = 'AssemblyName"

I fell at the first hurdle

```
        var test =
            from grp in project.ItemGroups.Cast<BuildProperyGroup>()
```

fails with an invalid cast.

Any clues as to where I am going wrong..

The solution I ended up with is as follows

```
        var PropG =
            from pg in project.PropertyGroups.Cast<BuildPropertyGroup>()
            from item in pg.Cast<BuildProperty>()
            where item.Name == "AssemblyName"
            select item.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I don't know what API you're programming, but if you want a property group, shouldn't you be looking at `project.PropertyGroups`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ItemsGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.project.itemgroups%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) are for collections of files, generally (such as all the `.cs` files in the `Compile` group). It sounds like you want to be poking around in the project's [PropertyGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.project.propertygroups%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) collection.

Comment: That worked for me  -  I have appended the solution to the question